# Why is $Y$ Hausdorff in this proof?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, filters, separation-axioms

On the page $214$, in **Proposition 21.6** of [this book](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=w6or65-Hw6UC&pg=PA214#v=onepage&q&f=false) how is $Y$ Hausdorff?

> Let $X$ be a set, $\beta X$ be a Stone space of $2^X$ and $\beta:X\to \beta X$ the homeomorphic embedding. If $Y$ is compact and $f:X\to Y$ is continuous then there is a unique continuous extension of $f$ to $\beta X$, $g:\beta X \to Y$ such that $f=g\circ \beta$

The Stone space here means sets of the form $\{A\subset X:x\in A\}$ for $x\in X$ (much like Stone-Cech compactification of $\mathbb{N}$). In the middle of proof author says that $Y$ is a Hausdorff, but it's not assumed in proposition. So I was confused how one could deduce $Y$ is Hausdorff. In fact doesn't $Y=\{0,1\}$ with indiscrete topology and $f:\mathbb{N}\to \{0\}$ gives a counterexample?

Comment: It probably is assumed, because "compact = quasicompact + Hausdorff".

Comment: @DanielFischer So basically in his terms compactness includes Hausdorff by definition?

Comment: Probably. That's how Bourbaki defined it. I haven't checked that book, however, so it _might_ be a mistake.

Comment: @Daniel: I just checked: Miraglia defines compactness for arbitrary spaces, merely noting in a footnote that some authors use *quasi-compct* when the space isn’t Hausdorff. However, Chapter 21 is **Projective Compact Hausdorff Spaces**, so he may be making a blanket assumption of Hausdorffness at this point.

Answer (score 1):

For the existence of $g$ we do not need Hausdorffness of $Y$, we do for the unicity. In your example with $Y$ a two-point indiscrete space, we can define define $g$ on $\beta X$ however we like as long as $g(\beta(n))= 0$ for all $n$, to obey the final condition and $Y$ being indiscrete means any map into it will be continuous. There are many different such $g$.

If $Y$ *is* assumed to be Hausdorff then as $g$ is determined on $\beta[X]$ by the condition $g \circ \beta = f$ and $\beta[X]$ is dense in $\beta X$, $g$ is fixed on a dense subset so uniquely determined by standard facts on Hausdorff spaces.